# Recompile xilinx kernel using Petalinux

Tags: apt-get, petalinux

I am working on a Ultra96 board, SOC Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC ZU3EG A484, running:

```
DISTRIB_ID=petalinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=2020.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=zeus
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="PetaLinux 2020.1"
```

Here my kernel version: `5.4.0-xilinx-v2020.1`

I am not familiar with petalinux so i need help about recompiling xilinx kernel to enable hugepages.

Is there any guide that explain step by step how to recompile the kernel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
petalinux-config -c kernel
```

which will take you to the kernel menuconfig, which you can then use to set hugepages.

Once you are happy with the changes and want to save them, you can run:

```
petalinux-build -c kernel -x finish
```

which will save the mods to project-spec/meta-user/recipes-kernel/devtool-fragment.cfg

which you can commit to git to keep the configuration changes.

See **Configuring Project Components** in https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2020_1/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide.pdf for more details